# Magento 2: mini cart icon not appearing in my custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

I'm creating a custom theme which is extended from Luma theme. For some reason, the Cart icon is not being displayed. I removed search box and Default welcome msg! through deafult.xml. But I'm sure I've not touched anything related to minicart. Can anyone please help where to look to fix it? 
Deafault.xml:

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">  

        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" /> 
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
    </referenceContainer>  

    <referenceBlock name="show_part" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content.target" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="header.panel" before="my_account_link" />
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo-white-outline.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">150</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">170</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Comment: post your `default.xml`

Comment: Hi Rajkumar,  added the default.xml for your reference.